# NSArray ArrayController SelectedObjects nil

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsarray

I have a coredata app with an Entity called Product.

In my interface I have an array controller for this entity called ProductAC. I have bound a table view and text fields to the array controller and can see the details, and I can add objects to it.

Now I want to create an export file for some of the objects. In the tableview I can select them, and then in the code I have this:

```
NSArray *uploadProducts = [ProductAC selectedObjects];
NSEnumerator *loop = [uploadProducts objectEnumerator];
```

This produces a nil value for the uploadProducts array.

How do I select the items to further process them? I have cleaned the file, closed and re-opened Xcode but I cannot seem to 'grab' the selected objects from the tableview?

thanks

Comment: Have you bound also table view > selectionIndexes to array controller > selectionIndexes?

Comment: yes and I have a popupbutton that has the selected object bound to the ProductAC.selection which also works.

Comment: so I can also connect buttons in the interface to selectNext and selectPrevious and they work. I also tried a different array controller and the selectedObjects for that was nil as well when it did have selected items in the tableview. It's as if I haven't connected something somewhere. I **can** add objects to the Array controller in my code, just not get any selectedobjects.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the table view selectionIndexes property bound to the corresponding property on your array controller.